# How to get image size in python-pillow after resize?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

`resized_image = Image.resize((100,200));`

`Image` is Python-Pillow Image class, and i've used the `resize` function to resize the original image,

How do i find the new file-size (in bytes) of the `resized_image` without having to save to disk and then reading it again

Comment: @OliverW. Oh, I Meant Image File Size, as in bytes

Answer (score 3):

The file doesn't have to be written to disk.  A file like object does the trick:

```
from io import BytesIO

# do something that defines `image`...   
img_file = BytesIO()
image.save(img_file, 'png')
print(img_file.tell())
```

This prints the size in bytes of the image saved in PNG format without saving to disk.

Comment: You can use an alternative to `BytesIO` that simply counts without needing to store the output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407717/python-image-library-how-to-compress-image-into-desired-file-size

Answer (score 0):

You can't. PIL deals with image manipulations in memory. There's no way of knowing the size it will have on disk in a specific format.

You can save it to a temp file and read the size using `os.stat('/tmp/tempfile.jpg').st_size`

Comment: I think there's a way to save to a byte counter instead of a file, but I can't find that answer at the moment.