# how to compress the image before uploading to s3 in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, amazon-s3, django-views

I am working on an application where a user can upload an image. I want to reduce the size of the image in 200-500kb.
This is my models.py file

```
class Report_item(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='*Title for the post e.g. item identity')
    image = models.ImageField(default="add Item image",
                          upload_to=get_uplaod_file_name)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + "      " + str(self.publish)
```

And this is my views.py file

```
class ReportCreate(generic.CreateView):
model = Report_item
fields = ['title','image']

def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    if form_class is None:
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = super(ReportCreate, self).get_form(form_class)
    form.fields['title'].widget = TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': '*Enter UID e.g. CBSE Marksheet Roll nunber 0506***'})
    return form

def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.owner = self.request.user
    self.object.save()
    return FormMixin.form_valid(self, form)
```

I am using Django 1.11 and S3 storage. Kindly help me to compress the image before uploading to s3.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13407861/2207154

Comment: What should I do with that answer? The answer even not show where to put that code in views or in a model and how that class needs to call.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So we need to define a save method in models in order to compress the image before save. Following code help me what I want to achieve for my problem.

```html
from io import BytesIO
import sys
from PIL import Image
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile


class Report_item(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='*Title for the post e.g. item identity')
    
    image = models.ImageField(default="add Item image",
                              upload_to=get_uplaod_file_name)

    def save(self):
        # Opening the uploaded image
        im = Image.open(self.image)

        output = BytesIO()

        # Resize/modify the image
        im = im.resize((100, 100))

        # after modifications, save it to the output
        im.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=90)
        output.seek(0)

        # change the imagefield value to be the newley modifed image value
        self.image = InMemoryUploadedFile(output, 'ImageField', "%s.jpg" % self.image.name.split('.')[0], 'image/jpeg',
                                        sys.getsizeof(output), None)

        super(Report_item, self).save()
```

WIth the help of this 5 Mb image compress to 4 kb approx.

Comment: Great the image is compressed a lot. Though is there a way to retain the orignal image height to width ratio?

Comment: @jitesh2796,  see my answer to retain the height to width ratio.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to upload an image after resizing it. You can use below code, just pass the image object and you will get resized image in return.

```
def GetThumbnail(f):
    try:
        name = str(f).split('.')[0]
        image = Image.open(f)
        image.thumbnail((400, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        thumbnail = BytesIO()
        # Default quality is quality=75
        image.save(thumbnail, format='JPEG', quality=50)
        thumbnail.seek(0)
        newImage = InMemoryUploadedFile(thumbnail,
                                   None,
                                   name + ".jpg",
                                   'image/jpeg',
                                   thumbnail.tell(),
                                   None)
        return newImage
    except Exception as e:
        return e
```

Answer (score 0):

@jitesh2796, to retain the height to width ratio, modify the accepted answer to include the following:

```py
def save(self):
       ...
       original_width, original_height = im.size
       aspect_ratio = round(original_width / original_height)
       desired_height = 100  # Edit to add your desired height in pixels
       desired_width = desired_height * aspect_ratio

        # Resize the image
        im = im.resize((desired_width, desired_height))
        ...
```

Note you may also need to use `round()` to ensure that the aspect ratio is an integer.